# Need to get documents for interval from latest timestamp and latest tiemstamp-N minutes in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, mongodb-query

I have documents in `mongodb` collection each with a `timestamp` (`field_name` = `expires`).

I need to get all the documents that are between latest `timestamp` present in collection and latest `timestamp-90` minutes.

For example,

Current clock time is 4pm.

Time-stamp of latest document in `Mongodb` is `2pm`.

*I need to get documents between `2pm` and `12.30pm`*

All the answers I found provide queries for the documents that lie within current clock time and `90 minutes` before that. (In this example, it would be `2.30PM to 4 PM`)

I could do it in 2 queries where, in first query, I get latest `timestamp` from `Mongodb` and then issue second query that matches documents between that `timestamp` and `90 minutes` older `timestamp`.

```
pipeline =[]
sort = {
    "$sort": {
        "expires": -1
    }
}

limit = {
    "$limit" : 1
}

pipeline.append(sort)
pipeline.append(limit)
```

And calculate

```
end_time = (result['result'][0])['expires']

start_time = end_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes=90)
```

And second query would be

```
pipeline = []
match = {
    "$match": {
        "expires" : {
            "$gt" : start_time,
            "$lte" : end_time,
            "$type": 18,
        }
    }
}
pipeline.append(match)
```

Is there a way to do this in single query using `aggregation` pipeline?

Please provide the link to the answer if posted already.

Thanks

Edit: I am using `Mongodb 2.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quiet simple, and can be done using the aggregation pipeline. You need not make expensive `$sort` or `$unwind` operations. One way of doing it would be,

- [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) all the records together, accumulate the records in an array named `result`. In the subsequent steps, we shall traverse through this array to keep only the records that we are interested in. For now, it will hold all the records in the collection. This is done, in order to get the [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) `expires` field for the entire collection.
- [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) through the array, [`$$DESCEND`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#descend) into those records which have an their `expire` field [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/) (*the maximum `expires` minus([`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/)) `90` minutes (`5400000ms`)*).
- [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) the result array containing the matching records.

`Pipeline`, which you can easily plug in to your `python` code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$group:{"_id":null,
         "result":{$push:"$$ROOT"},
         "maxTimeStamp":{$max:"$expires"}}},
{$redact:{$cond:[{$gte:[{$ifNull:["$expires","$maxTimeStamp"]},
                        {$subtract:["$maxTimeStamp",5400000]}]},
                 "$$DESCEND",
                 "$$PRUNE"]}},
{$project:{"result":1,"_id":0}}
])
```

For earlier versions, where the `$redact` stage is not available, you would need to use an alternative approach using, `$unwind` and `$project`,

- `$unwind` the result array.
- `$project` a field, which holds a `boolean` value, to indicate if the `expires` field matches our criteria.
- `$match` all the documents which are marked `selectable`.

modified approach,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$group:{"_id":null,
         "result":{$push:{"expires":"$expires"}},
         "maxTimeStamp":{$max:"$expires"}}},
{$unwind:"$result"},
{$project:{"selectable":{$cond:[{$gte:["$result.expires",
                                       {$subtract:["$maxTimeStamp",5400000]}]},
                                true,
                                false]},"result":1}},
{$match:{"selectable":true}},
{$project:{"result":1,"_id":0}}
])
```

Comment: Your answer is correct for mongodb versions 2.6 and above. Its correct but I should have mentioned, I am using mongodb 2.4. $redact operator was introduced in 2.6. Is there a way to do it in mongodb 2.4?

Comment: @KouBagade - updated the answer with an approach to solve for versions `< 2.6`.

Comment: Is $$ROOT variable present in 2.4? I could not find any reference to it in documentation. I believe it is introduced in version 2.6

Comment: @KouBagade - have updated my answer. You need to explicitly specify your fields in the document instead of the `$$ROOT` variable along with `expires`. I highly recommend you to upgrade your `mongodb` version.

Comment: @KouBagade - Feel free to `edit` my answer, and correct it - if you still face any version compatibility and you feel it can be corrected by a minor change to the answer.